It is possible to change the version from Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, without formatting
I am a new user of Ubuntu (dual-boot with W10), and I have version 24.04, it does not have the necessary packages for several programs that I need to run, the solution is to change to version 20.04. I can do a rollback without having to format the Ubuntu partition I have.
Greetings and thanks for your help

If 24.04 is missing some application which you need to use, please ask a new question. We can try to provide a workaround.

@user68186 That is an answer.

This is a XY Problem. You should tell us which programs you need to run and exact errors you get.

Why ask about rollback, without giving details as to what backup system you put in place and thus what rollback options exist for your chosen backup strategy.  You're without specifics (is. this is a Server install? Desktop install? what apps are used as that is rather critical! etc).   I'll provide a link to an answer I've written which CAN do what you want, but it has drawbacks so consider the details you've not told us first ! as to if its helpful for your system.

Yes, it is possible to downgrade from Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 without formatting, but it requires careful manual intervention.

In a word NO
It is not possible to go back to Ubuntu 20.04 from 24.04 without erasing 24.04 and installing 20.04. The Ubuntu installer USB for 20.04 can do this. Doing so will format the Ubuntu partition. (As far as I know you cannot go back to Windows 7 from Windows 10 without formatting C:!)
However, I do not recommend installing 20.04. In April of 2025 this version of Ubuntu will reach end of standard support. This means it will not get any security and other updates. For the same reason you should not go from Windows 10 to 7.
Hope this helps
